# Cut values inside a list until comma

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I have this list

```
list = [M111111:Example, B22222:Example Extended, T33333:Example]
```

And I need to get only the code before the ":" for example:

```
list = [M111111, B22222, T33333]
```

I tried using the split function but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
list.forEach(s-> newList.add(s.substring(0,s.indexOf(":")));
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your array consists of strings like this:

```
var list = ["M111111:Example", "B22222:Example Extended", "T33333:Example"];
```

you could use a loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i] = list[i].slice(0, list[i].indexOf(":"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> firstPart = Stream.of(list).map(s -> s.split(":")[0]).toList();
```

This will create a Stream of your list and for each element, split it on the `:` and return the first element, then collect that back into a `List<String>` that will contain, M111111, B22222, T33333, ...